# Magento 1.9.3.4 "Proceed To Checkout" button disappears after disabling Onepage Checkout

Tags: checkout, cart, onepage-checkout, magento-1.9.3.4

I have inherited the maintenance of a Magento 1.9.3.4 site that currently has Onepage Checkout enabled.  The owner wants to remove it, but when I disable, the Proceed to Checkout buttons disappear from the Cart page.  I have searched around and haven't found any solutions that fix my problem.

Comment: If you disable one page checkout then magento remove the proceed to checkout button as you have disabled it. What is the wrong? What do you exactly want?

Comment: I want the proceed to checkout button to direct me to the multi-page default checkout of magento

Comment: Do you mean multishipping?

Comment: No, the default checkout for Magento has multiple pages, one for each step.  I want to switch to this, but the checkout button is gone.

Comment: That is called onepage checkout in magento. So you need to enable it and test.

Comment: Try to disable your One Step Checkout module.

Comment: @GeorgeM I have tried this as well, but to no avail

Comment: Are you using any extension for Onepage checkout ?

Answer (score -2):

I met same problem and solved. My site installed a onestep checkout extension with My Theme and I disable the onestep checkout in the Theme's config and enable Onepage Checkout in Configuration. Hope it can help you. It should not be a final resolution.